# When checkbox is checked show hidden button and hide the visible button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am a beginner in javascript, hopefully you can help me with this problem..

I have 2 buttons in html form and 1 checkbox, 1 button should be hidden and the other is visible. My problem is how to show the hidden button and hide the visible button at the same time when the checkbox is checked..

I know how to hide/show the button `flip-ch1` but I can't do it to other button.

I have a script here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#flip-ch1').hide();
  $('#radio').mouseup(function() {
    $('#flip-ch1').toggle();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio">

  <button class="btn_style" id="ch1">Add</button>
  <button class="btn_style" id="flip-ch1">Add</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Toggle them both:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#flip-ch1').hide(); 
 $('#radio').mouseup(function () {
    $('#ch1').toggle();
    $('#flip-ch1').toggle();

 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, didn't spot `$('#flip-ch1').hide(); `

Comment: I tried it, the button ch1 hide and when i checked the checkbox the button flip-ch1 is shown, but when i unchecked the checkbox button ch1 is not showing..

Comment: How can you tell if they both have the same content of "Add"? Change the content to be different. My code works, according to your description.

Comment: As I say, my code works according to your description: clicking the checkbox will hide one button and show the other, repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line:

```
$('#ch1').toggle();
```

So, the complete js code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#flip-ch1').hide();
    $('#radio').mouseup(function () {
        $('#flip-ch1').toggle();
        $('#ch1').toggle();
    });
});
```

Do not get confused by the .hide(). It is used to hide one of the buttons only in the beginning. No need to use afterwards. The reason that you do not see any changes after toggling the checkbox, is that when first button is hidden the second one gets its place, the place does not remain empty. You can spot all this that I mentioned on inspect element of any major browser.

Comment: Thank you!! your such an angel.. thank you so much.. Thank you guys for the suggestion,, I appreciate it.. Thanks

Comment: I edited to give the explanation also based on the discussion of yours with @AndyG. You guys are having it wrong, so please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try **`$('#radio').is(':checked')`** as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#flip-ch1').hide();
  $('#radio').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#radio').is(':checked')) {
      $('#flip-ch1').show();
      $('#ch1').hide();
    } else {
      $('#flip-ch1').hide();
      $('#ch1').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio">

  <button class="btn_style" id="ch1">Add 1</button>
  <button class="btn_style" id="flip-ch1">Add 2</button>

</div>
```